# Reflect Endpoints as Model for Symfonys Serializer, also take shared response attributes into account

Tags: php, class, symfony, serialization, interface

**What I want**:

I try to deserialize the response from consuming an API Call in PHP. For my endpoints I like to have a Model, that way the Serializer can do it's magic.

**The response**:

```
{
    "count": 123,
    "next": "string",
    "previous": "string",
    "limit": 123,
    "offset": 123,
    "results": 
      [
        {...},
        {...}
      ]

}
```

Now, every response comes with the same "Base" attributes: count, limit, offset... etc. And then within the results each result is specific for the endpoint.

For Example:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "handle": "string"
}
```

In Symfony I call the following:

```
$this->serializer->deserialize($data, EndpointModel::class, 'json')
```

which should give me:

```
App\Api\Model\BaseModel {#541 ▼
  -count: 901
  -limit: 10
  -offset: 0
  -results: array:10 [▼
    0 => App\Api\Model\EndpointModel {#547 ▼
      -id: 3203
      -name: FooBar
    }
    1 => App\Api\Model\ResultModel {#549 ▶}
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Where I'm stuck**:

I created the `BaseModel.php`: https://hastebin.com/exagaworez.xml
And I have the `EndpointModel.php`: https://hastebin.com/tijinojixo.xml
So I call it with:

```
$this->serializer->deserialize($data, BaseModel::class, 'json')
```

This works just fine, but it only works for the one Endpoint. What I want to have is a Model for every Endpoint and call it somehow with the serializer so it converts my response.

How could I achieve something like that?

Since I need to describe the Endpoint also in the BaseModel it limits me to one Endpoint. I could just duplicate the code over and over to achieve my goal, but that seems bad.

I use Symfony, consume an API with http_client and want to transform the response with the serializer. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction or give me something to read :)

Thank you in advance! Let me know if you need more information

Comment: To be sure I got it, you don't actually call '$this->serializer->deserialize($data, EndpointModel::class, 'json')' right ? you call $this->serializer->deserialize($data, BaseModel::class, 'json') and it should internally deserialize results to EndpointModel ? Beside, results can contain several types of object ?

Comment: Yes, correct. I got it to work with the Symfony Serializer by calling the BaseModel and set the Type of $results to the EndpointModel. This way it would deserialize the data correctly. And yes, results can contain several types or Models of different Endpoints. If I call only the BaseModel and pass the "correct" Model with it or if I call the EndpointModel does not matter to me, not sure how the Serializer will work with that :) But surely something I can figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following structure which gives me my desired output:

Since my response on most of the endpoints has the same properties I created a `abstract class` called `BaseResponse`:

```
<?php


namespace App\Api\Response;


abstract class BaseResponse
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $count;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $limit;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $offset;


    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCount(): int
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $count
     */
    public function setCount(int $count): void
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLimit(): int
    {
        return $this->limit;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $limit
     */
    public function setLimit(int $limit): void
    {
        $this->limit = $limit;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getOffset(): int
    {
        return $this->offset;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset
     */
    public function setOffset(int $offset): void
    {
        $this->offset = $offset;
    }
}
```

*Here I store all the shared values of my responses.*

Then I create a `class` which `extends` my `BaseResponse` and takes care of specific properties or mainly my `results` like so:

```
<?php


namespace App\Api\Response;


use App\Api\Model\CenterModel;

class CenterResponse extends BaseResponse
{

    /**
     * @var CenterModel
     */
    private $results;

    public function __construct(CenterModel ...$results)
    {
        $this->results = $results;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResults(): array
    {
        return $this->results;
    }

    /**
     * @param $results
     */
    public function setResults(CenterModel ...$results): void
    {
        $this->results = $results;
    }
}
```

and finally I can create my Model which holds the structure of my endpoint object. This way I can keep track of the entity without the need of touching the response part. See here:

```
<?php


namespace App\Api\Model;

/**
 * Class CenterModel
 * @package App\Api\Model
 */
class CenterModel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

This way I can keep track of my responses and the endpoint models without duplication of too many lines of code.

Later I use the serializer and call the `CenterResponse` to deserialize the response. Like so:

```
$this->serializer->deserialize($data, CenterResponse::class, 'json');
```

The output then would be something like this:

```
Center.php on line 64:
App\Api\Response\CenterResponse {#541 ▼
  -results: array:10 [▼
    0 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#547 ▼
      -name: "Center Name here"
    }
    1 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#549 ▶}
    2 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#581 ▶}
    3 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#621 ▶}
    4 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#623 ▶}
    5 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#624 ▶}
    6 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#625 ▶}
    7 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#626 ▶}
    8 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#627 ▶}
    9 => App\Api\Model\CenterModel {#628 ▶}
  ]
  -count: 901
  -limit: 10
  -offset: 0
}
```

Maybe this is for some of you a good starting point :) For now I use this but maybe there is a different approach to this as well.